# How to obtain a lost version of an edited notepad [.txt] file on a Windows 10 hard drive using a SATA SSD to USB dongle

Tags: windows, forensics, windows-10, filesystems, data-recovery

About 1 year ago I had saved some code on a notepad text file (.txt) I was building using a Windows 10 computer. However, I deleted a portion of the code and saved the text file with a new c++ code patch thinking it was no big deal. However, I just now realized that the code I deleted in the text file is actually very important and I need it back, as the Arduino C++ code included a comment [//such as this] with an important phone number to a friend/colleague. Luckily I still have the SanDisk SSD and located the file location of the text file using a linux computer, connecting the SSD drive to the linux raspberry pi computer using a SATA to USB dongle I bought at Altex. Unfortunately, after multiple attempts at trying to use various linux recovery/forensics software on KaliOS such as hex editors I can't seem to get the version history of the text file to restore it to that previous version... even after searching using the hex editor on System32 and trying to get to the Notepad.exe log files, in addition to checking C:/users/username/AppData/local/Microsoft/InputPersonalization/TextHarvester for the keylogs to see if maybe by some miracle it stored the keystrokes. I can only pull up the current version. In addition, this was also after I tried using version history on the same Windows computer the drive booted into by right clicking the file and checking for properties, version history, etc on file explorer.

I have tried almost everything, [version history included] including the use of multiple Windows 10 computer forensics tools such as Paladian/Samurai and DiskDrill to obtain the lost version of the file, but I haven't been successful. Is there any remaining tips or tricks I can try that I haven't thought of yet? Since it has been a year the computer the SSD was connected has been turned on and off a couple of times, but I have been careful not to delete any more files or use it as often to prevent the hidden data from being overwritten. I know it's in there somewhere and if the FBI obtained my computer they would easily be able to restore that file probably in a snap using FLASH hardware analyzers, but I need to be able to do that same thing with just that single file without breaking the bank. Lastly, I do own an Arduino UNO including a USB Shield that has a 128x64 OLED screen, so maybe I can try bitbanging the usb protocoll to somehow analyze the pure raw binary data stored in the SSD through the SATA/USB converter to obtain the hidden data. Thanks, anything can help.

Comment: Your trying to recover a year old txt file on a HDD that’s been actively written to, and the file has been overwritten, there is zero chance of recovery a file like that.

Comment: "if the FBI obtained my computer they would easily be able to restore that file probably in a snap using FLASH hardware analyzers" -- that's a huge assumption

Comment: Have you tried a keyword search after carving data in Autopsy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question is based on incorrect assumption that data is recoverable under all circumstances (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

> I know it's in there somewhere and if the FBI obtained my computer
> they would easily be able to restore that file probably in a snap
> using FLASH hardware analyzers

This is a myth AFAIK.

Let's first analyze what happens at the file system level when you (partially) overwrite a file. The file system driver has two options and I have seen both happen (as in actually observed):

1. File is saved to the same clusters as original file.
2. New clusters are allocated to the file.

Note that clusters at the file system are statically mapped to LBA sector addresses and so that anything we do at cluster level happens at sectors mapped to the clusters.

If 1 then if:

**Conventional, spinning drive:** then on a conventional spinning drive your chances to recover the file's contents have just reduced to zero. Contrary to what some believe there's no way to recover previous data from some kind of magnetic residu or whatever. --> can not be recovered.

**Some NAND flash based drive:** then two things can happen (I will try avoiding the topic of *why* SSD's do the things the way they do).

a) If we assume an old very unsophisticated controller/firmware then the NAND pages mapped to our deleted data are erased (as they need to be before the page can be re-programmed) and data is written back to the same page. --> data can not be recovered.

b) A modern flash drive will reassign new physical NAND address to the newly saved data while it will flag the original NAND addresses as 'to be erased' by garbage collector. --> so here there's a window of opportunity to recover the data theoretically. However, the NAND previously assigned to the now deleted data is unmapped from LBA. This means conventional file recovery (including forensic tools) will no longer be able to recover data from these areas.

**Recover data from NAND flash based drives using more advanced techniques**

Basically there's two methods, the first involves **cooperation of the controller/firmware A**, the 2nd tries **bypass the controller altogether B**.

For both methods goes, that we can only recover data as long as the garbage collector did not erase the data yet, which is only a matter of time. Garbage collection typically takes place in idle time, but under circumstances can happen at any time (if there's a need for erased pages because more data is written than pages available, the controller has no choice other than make user wait and erase pages*).

We need to assume that if a SSD is connected to power, such background processing takes place. So, even if you do not use the SSD after deleting some data, even if you disconnect the data cable, as long as the drive is receiving power these processes will run.

**A:** Tools like Acelab's PC3000 can work with some ([not all by a long shot](https://blog.acelab.eu.com/pc-3000-ssd-list-of-supported-ssd-drives-regularly-updated.html)) SSD's and persuade the drive's firmware to grant access to non LBA mapped NAND memory. And by doing so, [you may be able to recover deleted data](https://blog.acelab.eu.com/pc-3000-ssd-how-to-bypass-the-trim.html).

Note that a similar process is applicable to SMR hard drives!

If the controller is not supported by PC3000 (IOW the firmware hasn't been reverse engineered for us) then we're up for a complex process of chip-sniffing, glitching and whatnot to try to hack the firmware and do all this work ourselves. A trend is that SSD's designers tend to get more and more restrictive and that over time this route of firmware reserve engineering is getting more difficult all the time. IOW, this is a huge effort to get just the phone number from a text file which for all we know may not even exist anymore.

**B:** Using Method 2 we remove the NAND chips from the drive and try to reverse engineer algorithms the controller used to write data to the NAND chips. In general this is only a viable method for recovering data from SD cards, USB flash drives and perhaps some very old SSD models.

My NAND reader + software to recover data from binary NAND dump:

[image: My NAND reader + software to recover data from binary NAND dump]

Main reason we can not apply this method to modern SSD's being [encryption](http://www.flash-extractor.com/library/SSD/SandForce/SF-2281VB1-SDC-S03__2c_88_04_4b__4x4): Modern SSD's encrypt data whether you ask them to do so or not. Many assume that as long as you do not set a password data is not encrypted, but setting a password merely means it will ask for a password for you to access the data and without the password it will just give you access to the data.

**Lucky shots**

Due to the way NAND flash works and sue to the way garbage collectors work there is a thing we call 'write amplification'. This means basically if we write a sector worth of data, in reality this may result in that sector being written to the drive multiple times. And even later, after the sector worth of data is written, for example the garbage collector may copy the sector and remap the LBA sector address to the new physical address in order to consolidate an erase block it can then actually erase. Research has shown that upto 10 copies of a sector can exist at some point.

This theoretically means, that if we can access the RAW data for example by bypassing the firmware, that deleted data may very still exist. Of course this assumes we're not dealing with encrypted data.

Anyway, CIA / FBI or whatever three letter agency being able to hook up a drive and effortlessly getting access to our long deleted data is a myth.

**Recovering text file**

If the contents of the file still exist inside LBA space then you should be able to find it, even if the file system is no longer referencing it. I usually use HxD and search the drive for a phrase that I know to exist inside the text file and that is sort of unique to avoid too many false positives.

If the phrase is detected either use ascii column to locate boundaries of the file, select that and copy into a new file.

If you know a phase from the text file and are unable to find it, then the file can not be recovered unless trying advanced stuff I gave above.